# JNI C++ findClass() in a spring boot fat/uber jar under BOOT-INF/lib/*.jar

Tags: c++, spring-boot, maven, jar, java-native-interface

I have a problem getting an included jar, for a bigger project, to find its own classes when included in a spring boot executable jar file.

The following code works when running the jar directly (ex: java -jar module.jar).

```cpp
jclass clazz = env->FindClass("com/module/Request");
```

It fails when ran in a greater spring boot jar

```
app.jar
 |-> BOOT-INF
     |-> lib
         |-> module.jar //module .class files
     |-> classes //app .class files (findClass() searches here?)
 |-> META-INF
 |-> org
```

How do I get the JNI to find the associated .class file within the module.jar? I've tried what feels like every possible variation of the following.

```cpp
env->FindClass("/BOOT-INF/lib/module.jar!/com/module/Request");
env->FindClass("file:/BOOT-INF/lib/module.jar!/com/module/Request");
env->FindClass("jar:file:/BOOT-INF/lib/module.jar!/com/module/Request");
env->FindClass("/home/root/app.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/module.jar!/com/module/Request");
env->FindClass("file:/home/root/app.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/module.jar!/com/module/Request");
env->FindClass("jar:file:/home/root/app.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/module.jar!/com/module/Request");
env->FindClass("/home/root/app.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/module.jar!/com/module/Request");
env->FindClass("file:/home/root/app.jar!file:/BOOT-INF/lib/module.jar!/com/module/Request");
env->FindClass("jar:file:/home/root/app.jar!jar:file:/BOOT-INF/lib/module.jar!/com/module/Request");
```

My jvm is initialized with

```cpp
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM *jvm, void *reserved) {
    return JNI_VERSION_1_6;
}
```

Comment: `FindClass` always takes a slash-separated classname. [The documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#wp16027) tells you which classloader is used: "FindClass locates the class loader associated with the current native method; that is, the class loader of the class that declared the native method. when FindClass is called through the Invocation Interface, there is no current native method or its associated class loader. In that case, the result of ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader is used. " I bet its not the one as the rest of your application

Comment: You will first need to figure out how class loading happens in your application: is it a direct call to a `ClassLoader` object? Is it setting the `ContextClassLoader` for the current thread? In the first case you may have to do the same and call `classLoader.findClass(...)` yourself.

Comment: So if I'm understanding this correctly. Running the module jar directly invokes the class loader of the module.jar as provided by *env. When running the app though we get the app's class loader as provided by its *env. How then do I get the env of the module from the env of the app (if that's even the right way to say it)?

Comment: If you have access to one of those classes from the Java side, you can just call `getClassLoader()`. Then either set the context class loader for the current thread before invoking JNI, or pass the `ClassLoader` object directly and call `ClassLoader#findClass(String)` from JNI.

Comment: JNI initiates the data transfer so I'll have to cache the class loader for Request.class.

So I now have "jclass classLoader" cached. How do I transform the basic jclass to perform the ```ClassLoader#findClass(String)``` function?

Comment: You need a ClassLoader *instance*, not a class. Then use `GetMethodID` to grab the `findClass` method and `CallObjectMethod` to call it. The result will be a `jobject` which you can cast to a `jclass`